# "render image" no colors, although you can see them through the camera

Tags: rendering

At the outset, I would like to write that I searched the internet, but did not find the answer.

The problem is that when I look through the camera I see colors, but when I want to "render image" (F12) the colors are gone.

Sorry, but I'm using google translator.[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, maybe you have hidden object in preview mode? please share your file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NDPnezzzBmL1lMEB1Y66JTFHslmANCNW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't see any color, whether I'm in camera view or in the final render, maybe in the Image Editor check the image textures you use?

Comment: all your images included in your uploaded file are just....white

Comment: and additionally no object has any material at all...

Comment: yes that's weird because their thumbnails are colored...

Comment: yes. saw that too...don't know what he did

Comment: but yeah, the objects in camera view have a material....but the textures are just white

Comment: Thank you very much for your willingness to help and for quick response: D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save all your images before rendering in Cycles.

[image]

Comment: Oh no .... How could I forget about it ... I watched the Keidy's tutorial and it was there, but I forgot after a long break. Thank you very much for your help !!!